# How to pair every element in a list with the other in a list of lists in Python?

Tags: python, list, append, combinations

I have a list that looks like:

```
results=[['000', '111', '000'], 
         ['110', '000', '101'], 
         ['000', '000', '000']]
```

I need to pair every element in the sublist with every other element (except itself).  Desired Output:

```
[[['000', '111'], ['000', '000'], ['111', '000']],
 [['110', '000'], ['110', '101'], ['000', '101']],
 [['000', '000'], ['000', '000'], ['000', '000']]]
```

Code Attempted:

```
samplefinal =[]
for sub_list in results:
    for i, j in combinations(range(len(sub_list)), 2):
        out = ['', '']
        sample3 = []
        for pair in zip(sub_list[i], sub_list[j]):
            if '-' not in pair:
                out[0] += pair[0]
                out[1] += pair[1]
            sample3.append(out)
    samplefinal.append(sample3)
print samplefinal

Output: [[['111', '000'], ['111', '000'], ['111', '000']], [['000', '101'], ['000', '101'], ['000', '101']], [['000', '000'], ['000', '000'], ['000', '000']]]
```

I am not quite sure where I may be going wrong. The indices and range work fine, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you want every combination of size 2 of your sublists. Use `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> results=[['000', '111', '000'], ['110', '000', '101'], ['000', '000', '000']]
>>> [[list(comb) for comb in itertools.combinations(sub,2)] for sub in results]
[[['000', '111'], ['000', '000'], ['111', '000']], [['110', '000'], ['110', '101'], ['000', '101']], [['000', '000'], ['000', '000'], ['000', '000']]]
```

And using pretty-print to make things clear:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> combos = [[list(comb) for comb in itertools.combinations(sub,2)] for sub in results]
>>> pprint(combos)
[[['000', '111'], ['000', '000'], ['111', '000']],
 [['110', '000'], ['110', '101'], ['000', '101']],
 [['000', '000'], ['000', '000'], ['000', '000']]]
>>>
```

Comment: I need a lists of combinations not tuples. It makes it harder for the rest of my code to have tuples

Comment: @Biotechgeek I think you mean a list of lists...that's a simple fix... check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a list comprehensation way to do that:

```
[ [ [ [L[i],L[j]] for i in range(j) ] for j in range(1,len(L))] for L in results]
```